# Show/Hide Checkbox in ASP.NET Datalist (nested)

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, nested, datalist

I have a nested ASP datalist that contains a label and a checkbox which is bound on page load.

During the binding a parse a string into the datalist bind method. If this string equals the value **1** I would like the checkbox to become visible for each item in the nested datalist.

And remain hidden is the value is **not 1**.

However, the code compiles and runs. It detects the string value as 1 but then does not make the check box visible. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Datalist:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" id="dgQuestionnaire" DataKeyField="QuestionID" CssClass="confirm">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="content_box" id="added_question">
            <h3>Question <asp:Label ID="lblOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex  + 1 %>'></asp:Label></h3>
            <p>Question Type</p>
            <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionText") %></p>
            <asp:DataList ID="nestedDataList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="sampleCheckbox" Visible="false" />
                    <p class="confirm_answer new"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AnswerTitle") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>    
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
public void BindParentDataList(int questionnaireID)
{
    // populate the datalist with items from the datatable.
    SendData = new OsqarSQL();
    DT = SendData.GetQuestionNameDataList(questionnaireID);
    dgQuestionnaire.DataSource = DT;
    dgQuestionnaire.DataBind();

    // each item in the datalist call BindNestedDataList method.
    foreach (DataListItem Item in dgQuestionnaire.Items)
    {
        BindNestedDataList(Item.ItemIndex, DT.Rows[Item.ItemIndex][2].ToString());
    }
}

public void BindNestedDataList(int ItemIndex, string _questionType)
{
    // get questionID value for the current datalist item and populate the answers for the question.
    int questionID = Convert.ToInt32(dgQuestionnaire.DataKeys[ItemIndex]);
    DT = SendData.GetAnswerTitle(questionID);
    DataList nestedDataList = (DataList)dgQuestionnaire.Items[ItemIndex].FindControl("nestedDataList");

    if(_questionType == "1")
    {                
        foreach (DataListItem Item in nestedDataList.Items)
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)Item.FindControl("sampleCheckbox");
            checkbox.Visible = true;
        } 
    }
    nestedDataList.DataSource = DT;
    nestedDataList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems right only you have written the code in wrong place, write this in Row/Item bound event and get the current binding row instead of row[itemindex]